# ¿Cómo agregar un background-imagen con Dompdf?

Tags: laravel, dompdf

Llevo días intentando agregar una imagen de fondo a la vista que tengo creada para que genere el documento PDF pero no hay manera.
Este es mi controlador:

```
function resultadodiploma()
{
   $primer_apellido = Auth::guard('usuario')->user()->primer_apellido;
   $segundo_apellido = Auth::guard('usuario')->user()->segundo_apellido;
   $diploma_usuario = UsuarioDiploma::get();
   $imagen_diploma = DB::table('imagen_diploma')
    ->join('usuario_diploma','usuario_diploma.proyecto_id', '=', 'imagen_diploma.proyecto_id')
    ->select('imagen_diploma.nombre')
    ->where('usuario_diploma.usuario_id', '=', Auth::guard('usuario')->user()->id)
    ->get();
   $pdf = \PDF::loadView('Frontend.obtenerdiploma.obtenerdiploma', compact('dia', 'mes', 'year', 'nombre', 'primer_apellido', 'segundo_apellido', 'imagen_diploma', 'nombre_proyecto'))->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
            return $pdf->download('diploma.pdf');
}
```

Y esta la vista donde irán a parar los datos.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
        html{
            background-image: url({{ url('/images/aspecto-proyecto/imagen_diploma/'.$nombre_proyecto[0]->titulo_proyecto.'/'.$imagen_diploma[0]->nombre)}}); ;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: center center;
            background-size: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        @page {margin:0px;}
        .contenedor{
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="contenedor">

            <h1>{{$nombre}} {{$primer_apellido}} {{$segundo_apellido}}.</h1>
            <p>{{$dia}} de {{$mes}} de {{$year}}</p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Cuando hago click al respectivo botón para que lo descargue, este se descarga correctamente pero la imagen no... si la imagen la añado de esta manera `/images/aspecto-proyecto/imagen_diploma/Proyecto 1/diploma.jpg` si funciona.
Ya he comprobado que las variables que obtengo no estén vacios o nullos, los datos que obtengo del controllador están correctamente.

Comment: Al final he solucionado este problema añadiendo el background al body de esta manera `background-image: url(/images/aspecto-proyecto/imagen_diploma/{{$nombre_proyecto[0]->titulo_proyecto}}/{{$imagen_diploma[0]->nombre}});`

Comment: Publica la respuesta y dale como resuelta.en la sección de respuesta y no en la de comentarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta fue la solución:
añadiendo el background al body de esta manera `background-image: url(/images/aspecto-proyecto/imagen_diploma/{{$nombre_proyecto[0]->titulo_proyecto}}/{{$imagen_diploma[0]->nombre}});`

Comment: Entonces por favor considera marcar esta respuesta como la solución por favor

Comment: @Cristian tengo una duda, ¿Que version de dompdf estan utilizando?

Answer (score 0):

Para que se vea la imagen tienes que hacerlo de la siguiente manera: `{{ base_path() . '/images/aspecto-proyecto/imagen_diploma/'.$nombre_proyecto[0]->titulo_proyecto.'/'.$imagen_diploma[0]->nombre }}` o `{{ public_path('/images/aspecto-proyecto/imagen_diploma/'.$nombre_proyecto[0]->titulo_proyecto.'/'.$imagen_diploma[0]->nombre) }}`